# Sonatype Nexus - Disabling "Analyze Application" button in Component View

Tags: nexus, sonatype

all!

I need to disable the "Analyze Application" button in Nexus' component view before this software is ready for our production systems. For various reasons, we can't allow that function to work on production servers.

Is there a convenient way to disable it that I am missing? I've perused the user manual and the function is only even mentioned once. Additionally, there is no configuration option to disable it. I even went so far as to pull a network traffic report and run it through Wireshark to try to find an IP/Port to block, but no such luck.

If anyone has experience disabling this function I would greatly appreciate any guidance that can be offered.

Comment: Just for sake of clarity, why do you need to disable this? It will be helpful for us at Sonatype to understand what you are trying to avoid.

Comment: My understand is that we're concerned that we'll have sensitive, DoD regulated information in the file names that would get sent out by this function. We could, of course, not use sensitive information in the names, but easier to disable the function entirely than depend on people to not name things foolishly, and not click a big inviting button. At the end of the day I am a grunt and just doing what my bosses tell me, so I may have lost something in translation here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Sonatype. There is no application setting to disable this functionality. What you *can* do is add clm.sonatype.com to your hosts file on whatever machine is hosting Nexus. The functionality will still appear operational on the front end, but a quick look at nexus.log will reveal that it is unable to resolve the hostname and throws a stack trace to the log instead.

Also, they opened a JIRA request for the functionality and marked it as high, so this may become an option in the future.

Comment: P.S. The solution we ultimately went with (so we don't go to prison for leaking ITAR data) was to set up an external Nexus proxy in the DMZ, and a second Nexus within the internal network. The external Nexus pulls out two proxied repositories (Maven Central and JBoss I think), and then the internal Nexus pulls those two proxied repos from the DMZ Nexus. The internal Nexus also hosts our internal repositories. This way the developers have one repo to draw from, and that repository has zero internet access - it can only contact the DMZ Nexus and our internal network.